need a different algorithm for my code of iterating all the sub strings of a given string
So the question is to give the length of the longest substring of the given string in which the number of occurrences of "ab" is equal to number of occurrences of "ba".
For example if input is "abba" the output should be 4 because "abba" has one occurrence of "ab" and one occurrence of "ba" so the answer is 4.
here's my code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, x;
    string s;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        cin >> x;
        cin >> s;
        int maxlen = 0;
        bool found = false;

        if(x<=2){
            maxlen = 1;
        }
        else {

        for (int i = x; i >= 2; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= x - i; j++)
            {
                int ab = 0, ba = 0;
                for (int k = j; k < j + i - 1; k++)
                {
                    if (s[k] == 'a' && s[k + 1] == 'b')
                    {
                        ab++;
                    }
                    else if (s[k] == 'b' && s[k + 1] == 'a')
                    {
                        ba++;
                    }
                }

                if (ab == ba)
                {
                    maxlen = i;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        }
        cout << maxlen << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

i have simply used a triple nested loop to check one by one but this has made the time complexity n^3 which is not being accepted in a contest i gave recently
i tried the straight forward approach of seperating all the sub strings and checking one by one but i need a more optimized code to reduce its time complexity

You mean "choose a different algorithm to solve this problem" rather than "optimize". Optimization isn't going to reduce time complexity from n^3.

Look for the "sliding window" algorithm.

I'd imagine finding all the locations of ab and ba first then from that list working out the best substring would be a better approach

The question specification is incomplete. Can other characters appear in the substring or must it be entirely made up of a and b characters. IOW what are the scores for aba, abbba and abcba ?

I don't think that matters @Martin. It says 'the number of occurrences of "ab" is equal to number of occurrences of "ba"', in which I see no ambiguity. aba, abbba and abcba all have exactly one occurrence of ab and one occurrence of ba.

First of all, you have a small error in your algorithm:
        if(x<=2){
            maxlen = 1;
        }

When x is 2, the result could be 2. For instance if the input is "aa" or "qr" (anything other than "ab" or "ba"), then the output should be 2, not 1. So this if condition should be x < 2 instead of x<=2.
More efficient algorithm
You can do this in one iteration over the input string. Use the concept of "balance", which signifies the balance between the number of "ab" and "ba" found so far. You'd start out with a balance of 0, and would increment it when you encounter "ab" and decrement it when you encounter "ba". For each distinct value of that balance keep track at which index you encountered that balance the first time. You could use an array for that (but then add some offset to the balance to avoid negative indices). Now whenever you arrive at a balance that was encountered before, the substring between those two occurrences is a candidate solution.
Here is an implementation of that algorithm:
int getMaxLength(std::string s) {
    int n = s.length();
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    int maxLength = 1;
    // Define the balance as some int value that can serve 
    //   as an index in firstOccurrenceOfBalance even if it decreases:
    int balance = n / 2;
    int firstOccurrenceOfBalance[n] = {}; // Initialized with all zeroes
    // We start with a given balance, and thus we have an occurrence of
    //   it at the first position (we use 1-based position)
    firstOccurrenceOfBalance[balance] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (s[i - 1] == 'a' && s[i] == 'b') balance++;
        if (s[i - 1] == 'b' && s[i] == 'a') balance--;
        // If this is the first time we encounter this balance...
        if (firstOccurrenceOfBalance[balance] == 0) {
            // ... then mark the current position as its first occurrence:
            firstOccurrenceOfBalance[balance] = i + 1;
        } else {
            // We had this balance before, so the substring between that first 
            //     occurrence and this one is a potential solution.
            // The character we are at is inclusive, so add 1
            maxLength = std::max(maxLength, i + 2 - firstOccurrenceOfBalance[balance]);
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}

In your main call it like this:
int main() {
    int numTests, strLength;
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> numTests;
    while (numTests--) {
        std::cin >> strLength; // Can be ignored, as we have s.length()
        std::cin >> s;
        int maxLength = getMaxLength(s);
        std::cout << maxLength << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

